# If in Sum combined in SQL query, and Yii ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

First of all, sorry for my English. I need some help with this. Recently I started my first project with Yii, and everything is great, framework seems to be perfect, but I have a little problem with selecting records from the database using ActiveRecord.

Let's say that I have following code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = '*, user.*, sum(if(points > 0, 1, 0)) as rank_points, sum(points) as all_points, count(*) as count_all';
$criteria->group = 'user_id';
$criteria->order = 'all_points desc';

$users = Types::model()
                ->with('user')
                ->findAll($criteria);
```

I have problems with this

```
sum(if(points > 0, 1, 0)) as rank_points
```

when I'm using it, I get the following error:

> Active record "Types" is trying to select an invalid column "sum(if(points > 0". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.

The problem is that this query is correct, and I can use it manually, or (I haven't tried but I think it should work) with query builder. I'm determined to do this with AR, so here is my question; is it possible, to do this as stated? Am I doing something wrong, or is it a more complicated problem?

Thanks in advance for every reply.

Comment: Do you have rank_points defined as an attribute in your class?

Comment: @Skatox i haven't had, but i defined it, and i've got the same error. What else, i have defined the all_points and count_all properties in the model and it's working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the select as a array

```
$criteria->select=array('*', 'sum(if(points > 0, 1, 0)) as rank_points','sum(points) as all_points', 'count(*) as count_all');
```

The problem with your code is that as your `select` parameter is a string, Yii try to get all columns by `explod`ing with a `,` and the `,` in your `IF` statement makes yii to think it as two seperate select values

Comment: I can promise you that i tried this before, with no success, but i just try it again as you say and it's working propely, i don't know what kind of sorcery it is, but really thanks anyway, i will know what to do in the feature :)